# Python Seaborn placing legend outside with a title

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

My seaborn plot is working fine. I am having issues in legend. The legend is placed inside the plot bydefault. But when I place it outside, the title goes missing.

[image]

My code:
import seaborn as sns

```
sns.barplot(x='xdata',y='ydata',hue='Rank',
            data=df,
            palette='jet_r')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.9),loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Present output: the legend is placed outside but the title is missing. How to solve this?
[image]

Comment: Seaborn 0.11.2 has a new function `sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.9),loc='upper left')` that by default keeps the legend intact.  Note that you need `ax = sns.barplot(....)` to grab the `ax`.  You might need to call `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.show()` to fit everything nicely into the plot.

Comment: @JohanC Yes! it solved the issue. Thanks for letting me know about `sns.move_legend()` which I did not know before.